# Графичиский движок. Вопросы проектирования

Tags: проектирование

Пытаюсь разработать некое подобие графического движка используя OpenGL 4.3 и у меня возникли сложности с проектированием оного.

Моя цель пока проста: есть набор значений (координаты вершин, текстур, нормалей) и по ним  рисуется графический примитив, например квадрат. У меня почти получилось все спроектировать, но когда дело дошло до текстур, пришлось лепить множество костылей, что свидетельствует об ошибках проектирования. Я сам не могу создать хороший проектный план для реализации подобного вывода и хотел бы попросить помощи. Быть может кто нить уже делал подобный граф движок и мог бы посоветовать как бы все это разбить, как создавать иерархию наследований. Своё подобие граф движка буду использовать как простое АПИ для создание банальных игр как например змейка, сапер, шахматы и прочих.

P.S. Большая просьба не советовать готовые решения типа юнити и подобных.

Comment: Вы все делаете правильно, проектный план Вам никак не поможет, а советы от других только сильнее запутают. Продолжайте дальше делать. Сделайте змейку на основе своей библиотеки (пускай большинство методов будут не реализованы). Так Вы поймете требования к подобной библиотеке и глубину проблем. А потом уже с вершины собственного опыта можете смотреть реализации от других. Иначе все равно не поймете, или Вам покажется что понимаете.

Comment: Есть правило 3. До тех пор, пока у вас не будет 3 разных игр, использующих ваш движок, движком его толком-то и называть нельзя. Так что делайте игру с оглядкой на переиспользование частей кода, потом вторую, а потом выделяйте движок в отдельную сущность.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но, увы, слишком общий для Stack Overflow